# Input element values are undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function that is not working as I expected.  The function should loop through the `input` boxes and display an alert with the `input`'s value.  For some reason, the `input`s are all returning an `undefined`.  I am sure the ids of the `input` elements are correct.  I can perform other actions on the input (change color, set `.innerHTML`), but I can't seem to collect the values.  Can someone point out what I may be doing wrong?

```
function submitHours(){
    var table = document.getElementById('StudentList');
    var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var r = 1; r < rows.length+1; r++) {
        for(x=1; x<=25; x++){
            document.getElementById(r+'day'+x).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            alert(document.getElementById(r+'day'+x).value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: only certain HTML elements have a `.value` - input's, option's etc - without seeing your HTML, how can we tell what elements with id's `1day1` to `Nday25` are?

Comment: `document.getElementById(r+'day'+x)` by writing this what type of element you are trying to select?

Comment: why don't you include your html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're selecting an element that *contains* the `input` you're targeting, but not the `input` itself. This is why you can set the `.innerHTML`, but not get the `.value`.

To get the value, do this:

```
function submitHours(){
    var rows = document.querySelector('#StudentList > tbody:first-child > tr');

    for (var r = 1; r < rows.length+1; r++) {
        for(var x=1; x<=25; x++){
            var input = document.querySelector('#' + r+'day'+x + " input");
            input.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            alert(input.value);
        }
    }
}
```

There's probably a more efficient way to do this, but I can't tell without seeing your markup.

Comment: Thanks.  I had the id on the td element and not the input itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `innerText` instead of `value`:

```
for(x=1; x<=25; x++){
  document.getElementById(r+'day'+x).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  alert(document.getElementById(r+'day'+x).innerText);
}
```

Comment: `.innerText` on an `input` element?

Comment: Not really. They could be any element, and not even necessarily in the same table, though I'd imagine they're in the table cells. Anyway, he mentioned "input" elements several times.

Comment: Could be that the targeted ID is on the cell but he wants an input nested within somewhere.

Comment: I will edit my answer once he has posted the HTML structure